# Contador de registros o columnas de una base de datos Mysql mediante PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Quisiera saber el total de ***números de columnas o registros ingresados*** en una tabla y lo muestre por pantalla.

Por ejemplo en la tabla tengo tres registros o columnas y necesito que me arroje el numero **3** 
[image: Por ejemplo en la tabla tengo tres registros o columnas y necesito que me arroje el numero 3]

Lo que tengo es lo siguiente

```
 global $connect;


$query = "SELECT count(*) as total from Asistente ";

mysqli_query($connect, $query) or die (mysqli_error($connect));

    $data=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    echo $data['total'];


mysqli_close($connect);
```

mensaje de error

> mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null
>   given in

Comment: Quisiera saber el total registros ingresados, aparece al principio

Comment: la he editado @x-rw

Comment: esta de esa manera y aun arroja el error

Comment: ya le has asignado el resultado de la consulta a la variable result? $result = mysqli_query($conexion, $query) en todo caso si solo necesita saber el numero de filas es mas facil utilizar la funcion mysqli_num_rows

Comment: Exacto,no existe $result

Comment: en todo caso si solo necesita saber el numero de filas es mas facil utilizar la funcion mysqli_num_rows

Comment: Claro, pero su pregunta tiene que quiere saber numero de columnas y registros, en su defecto serian lo mismo no?, ya que si cuento o busco el numero de rows daría el mismo valor, o me equivocó?

Comment: @AllanMG deberias convertir tu comentario en respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

te falta asignar un valor a tu variable `$result`

```
global $connect;


$query = "SELECT count(*) as total from Asistente ";

if ($result = mysqli_query($connect, $query)) {

    $data=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    echo $data['total'];

}
mysqli_close($connect);
```

Comment: Gracias ! ah funcionado, ahora tengo el numero de registros !

Answer (score 0):

Si metes la $query en vez del $result? Porque por eso te dice que un valor esta nulo, ya que no existe $result.

```
global $connect;


$query = "SELECT count(*) as total from Asistente ";

mysqli_query($connect, $query) or die (mysqli_error($connect));

    $data=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);

    echo $data['total'];


mysqli_close($connect);
```